# Angular Typeahead with post data

Tags: angularjs, typeahead

I want to implement typeahead in angular. For some reasons, Instead of passing params through GET method I want to achieve it through POST method. What's wrong with the below code ?

HTML:

```
    <div ng-controller="TypeaheadCtrl">
        <h4>Asynchronous results</h4>
        <pre>Model: {{asyncSelected | json}}</pre>
        <input type="text" ng-model="asyncSelected" placeholder="Data loaded via $http" typeahead="name for name in getNames($viewValue)" typeahead-loading="loadingNames" typeahead-no-results="noResults" class="form-control"/>
        <i ng-show="loadingNames" class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></i>
        <div ng-show="noResults">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>
            No Results Found
        </div>
    </div>
```

JS: (XQuery is the service)

```
    myApp.controller('TypeaheadCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

        $scope.getNames = function(val) {

            $http({
                method  : 'POST',
                url     :  './myResource?workbench/APP16/service/myservice.xq',
                data    :  '<data><name>'+val+'</name></data>',
                headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/xml' }
            })
            .sucess(function(response)
            {  
                return( response.hint.map(function(item){
                return item.text;
                }));
            });
        };

    });
```

Response Data:

```
    {
        "hint": [
            {
                "pattern": "clinicInfo/name/Rudvik",
                "text": "Rudvik",
                "type": "clinicProfile",
                "image": null
            },
            {
                "pattern": "clinicInfo/name/raju",
                "text": "raju",
                "type": "clinicProfile",
                "image": null
            }
        ]
    }
```

When I use console.log on return data I get,

```
    console.log( response.hint.map(function(item){
                return item.text;
                }));
```

I got: [Rudvik,raja]

But In the typehead I get nothing. How to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there, you just forgot the `return` in the `getNames` function.

Replace:

```
$scope.getNames = function(val) {
    $http(...).sucess(function(response) {  
            // ...
    });
};
```

with:

```
$scope.getNames = function(val) {
    return $http(...).sucess(function(response) {  
            // ...
    });
};
```

Comment: when I place return before $http, my post method didn't call service